# Optimizing the phase model of CMS-project

Tags: software-development, project-team, time-management, development-process, customer-experience

We are working since couple of years with an `CMS`. 
Until now our working `model` was divided in the following `phases`:

> 1. Preparation
>
>    - Online Meetings
>    - Soft Kick off-online
>    - Scoping Workshop
>    - Concepting
>    - Summarization
>    - Output: Proposal
> 2. Realisation
>
>    - Installation/Hosting
>    - Design & Theming
>    - Konfiguration
>    - Programming
>    - Quality Assurance
>    - Training preparation
> 3. Training & Testing
>
>    - Admin-Training
>    - User Acceptance Testing
>    - UAT attendance
>    - Finishing
> 4. Go Live
>
>    - Preparation
>    - Transformation from Test to Live
>    - Acceptance Live-Instance
>    - GO LIVE
>    - Post Go Live attendance

The problem with this model is, that we are strugleling in the most of the time with the projects. In each moment we have misscommunication or lack of resources.
Right now we have about 30% work of the preparation and the other 70% are in the last 3 phases. As it seems that is not enough. It is every time the same CMS, just with adapting some changes to fit the customer (as in the configuration, as well in the code). 
How to transfer that, so most of the work happens even before the actual realisation of the project? Or even to automate it? It won't bother us, if we make one big preparation and the just fit it to each project. But where to finde guidance for such work to be done?

We have in our team:

- back end developer
- front end developer
- project manager
- support team (doing mostly configuration

Comment: It is very difficult to understand both the problem you are trying to resolve and exactly what you are asking for. Forgetting the details of the team and the work for the moment- what is the problem you need to solve?

Comment: I don't see a problem; you have a process and you're mature enough to know that 70% of your effort is spent in 3 phases of the project. I'd be thrilled to be in your shoes.   Are you not meeting your deadlines/projections?  I think the answer might be embedded in ". . . every time the same CMS....", but I don't understand the problem described by that sentence.

Comment: Are you developing a content management system (CMS) or using one to manage your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A phased approach to CMS implementation often indicates that you've optimized for resource efficiency rather than flow efficiency. While this does a good job of keeping your specialists productive, it usually leads to slower delivery times for features, due to the hand-offs between team members or the transition between phases.

See Johanna Rothman's series on resource vs. flow efficiency for some ideas about changing your working model.
http://www.jrothman.com/mpd/agile/2015/09/resource-efficiency-vs-flow-efficiency-part-1-seeing-your-system/